# Multiple type parameter in java

Tags: java, function, class, types, declaration

I need a function that accepts both types of arguments and has the same body.
How can I do it?
For example:

```
// I have:
public someFunction(Pageable input) { the same body }
public someFunction(Sort input) { the same body }

// I need
public someFunction(PageableOrSort input) {the same body}
```

Comment: Can you give `Pageable` and `Sort` a compatible interface? If not, best you can do is `Object`.

Comment: Inside a body i have function using CrudRepository and that type must be specified.
I'm starting to program in Java and I don't know the interfaces or generics range enough, but I think it can be done simply.

Comment: *function using CrudRepository* - Does that mean that `Pagable` and `Sort` are some kind of *Data Transfer Object*s (Objects carrying data only, no other methods except getters and setters)? does *the same body* mean it calls  methods with same Names on either of the classes  `Pagable` and `Sort`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, but this is bad practice:

```
public void someFunction (Object input){
        if (input instanceof Pageable) { 
            Pageable pageable = (Pageable) input;
            /* do something else */ }

        if (input instanceof Sort) { 
            Sort sort = (Sort) input;
            /* do something else */ 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it can be helpful. But if the wrong type is given, the program will return an error during execution instead of at the compilation stage.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you have to be careful with that. Therefore, it is better to make separate methods for individual types.
Or you can make wrapper classes for your classes (if they are classes of the standard library), implement them to one common interface, and put this interface as a parameter of your method. If it’s not clear, let me know, I will write in more detail in a another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a wrapper object that has a `Pageable` property and a `Sort` property:

```
public Class MyWrapper {

    public Sort mySort;
    public Pageable myPageable;

}
```

Then you can set both properties then have your method have a `MyWrapper` as a parameter.

But what is the reason for wanting a single method? Having an overloaded method is good practice in a situation like this and you can abstract your method body to where there is no much duplicate code depending on the logic.

Comment: How to use it and return myPageable if exist, or mySort if mypageable not exist using generic types?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your function `someFunction` does something like this

```
input.doA();
input.doB();
```

Then create an interface that contains those two methods

```
interface PageableOrSort {
    void doA();
    void doB();
}
```

and define your method as

```
void someFunction(PageableOrSort input) {
    input.doA();
    input.doB();
}
```

And make your classes implement the interface

```
public class Pageable implements PageableOrSort {
    @Override
    public void doA() {
         //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void doB() {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

and the same for the other class. Then you can call the method with any class implementing the interface

```
Pageable pageable = new Pageable();
//...
this.someFunction(pageable)
```